# When image is sent to server I get this error "java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 1869"

Tags: java, image, networking, server, client

I have a client server application, the image sends successfully but the server does not fully receive it because of that error in the title. This is my code:

Server:     public void upload() throws IOException {

```
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream (sock.getInputStream());

        String str,extn = ""; 

        str = dis.readUTF();

        int flag=0,i; 

            for(i=0;i<str.length();i++) 
            { 

                if(str.charAt(i)=='.' || flag==1) 
                { 
                flag=1; 
                extn+=str.charAt(i); 
                }
            }
```

//**********************reading image*********************************//

```
           if(extn.equals(".jpg") || extn.equals(".gif")) 
              {             
                File file = new File("RecievedImage"+str); 
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);

                //receive and save image from client 
                byte[] readData = new byte[8]; 
                while((i = dis.read(readData)) != -1) 
                {
                    fout.write(readData, 0, i); 
                    if(flag==1) 
                    { 
                    System.out.println("Image Has Been Received"); 
                    flag=0; 
                    } 
                } 
            fout.flush(); 
            fout.close(); 

              }

           executorService.shutdown();
    }
```

Run method:

```
        public void run ()
    { 
        try{

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("datalogging.txt", true);
        PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(writer);
        InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        fileName = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(fileName);
        System.out.println("Message recieved");

        if (fileName.charAt(0) == 'R') {
            download();
            print.println(df.format(dateobj) + " : " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + " : " + "download"  );

        } else{
            upload();
            print.println(df.format(dateobj) + " : " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + " : " + "upload"  );
        }


        print.close();
        writer.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }



    }
```

Any help?

Comment: It's very unclear what the context of all this is. What's sending data to the server? If it's not using `writeUTF` then that's probably the issue. It would really help if you'd provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, and make sure you format your code properly to make it more readable, too.

Comment: Image is not text! So [`dis.readUTF()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF--) does not make sense for binary data.

Comment: I am using writeUTF on the client side, when the program is ran is runs perfectly up until the dis.readUTF() method. What do you advise using instead of dis.readUTF()? @Seelenvirtuose